# Render slows down in the last couple minutes

Tags: rendering

Beginner here. I started a few days ago and began using blender 2.8 yesterday. I'm not sure if it's normal but I notice my renders slow down in 2.8 when they're almost done. It didn't happen in 2.79. It's so much that the last 1 minute of time remaining takes 10 minutes. The image is also almost completely rendered, with almost no tiles showing any noise.

I have GPU and CPU rendering set up, my GPU is a gtx1080 and CPU is in i5-4670k at 4.5ghz. Not sure if that's relevant but thought I would add it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Everything is just simple.

i5-4670k heve 8 logical cores wich one by one render slower that one GPU.

[image: GPU + CPU]

Can see, how GPU overtaking CPU cores. And then they remain, but the GPU is not involved in process. There is also an inaccuracy in the calculation of time.

It would be better if the CPU represented only one tile. I have [posted](https://developer.blender.org/D2873#72376) about it on developer.blender.org.

You need to **render only by GPU** and it will become faster then with CPU.

Comment: Thanks man! I had tested it earlier and you're for sure right. My render was 18 minutes with just GPU vs 27 mins with both.

Comment: @nnostad23 Don't post thanks as a comment, if the answer helped you upvote it, and if it completely solved your problem consider marking it as accepted